# Joining random points to layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have one vector layer and one random points layer (generated from random points in extent). How can I join / merge to keep only the random points that align with the map layer?

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like a trivial case of `intersect`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only the points inside the polygon use Select by location under Vector-Research tools-Select by location.

Then right-click layer - Export - Save selected features as

If you want to join the features, for example to get polygon attributes join to the points use:
Vector-Data management tools-Join attributes by location

Or Intersect under Vector - Geoprocessing tools - Intersection